# How to fix following .htaccess 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but couldn't find a value in them.

I am doing the following redirect in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/old/url/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /new-url/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The final result I would like to get is http://old/url/page/2 --> http://new-url/page/2
but I am getting getting wrong urls, like http://new-url/old/url/page/2
could someone give me a hint how to include only /page/2/ part appended in the final url redirect

thanks

Comment: Anyone, I understand it is a quick thing, but I could really use direction or help of someone who know it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^/old/url/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ /new-url/$1 [L,R=301]
```